# Enable the Ethernet in stm32F769I-Disco using c

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, ethernet

*The main aim is to get the IP address of the stm32 board using the ethernet port but I am not there yet. In code a temporary breakpoint occurred at HAL_Init();
I am having trouble in finding what's wrong with code also had difficulty in knowing the working of the api function in the code. Need help ,Thank you.*

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "lwip.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sockets.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include <lwip/netdb.h>
#include "lwip/netif.h"
#include "netif/etharp.h"
#include "ethernetif.h"


/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

osThreadId defaultTaskHandle;

struct netif gnetif;
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument);
//static void udp_client_connect(void);
static void MX_LWIP_Process(void);

extern struct netif gnetif;
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  //initialize the lwip stack
  MX_LWIP_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

 // udp_client_connect();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* definition and creation of defaultTask */
  osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* Start scheduler */
 // osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      MX_LWIP_Process();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


static void MX_LWIP_Process(void)
{
    ethernetif_input(&gnetif);

     ethernetif_set_link(&gnetif);
      if (netif_is_link_up(&gnetif) && !netif_is_up(&gnetif))
      {
          netif_set_up(&gnetif);
          dhcp_start(&gnetif);
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that a "temporary breakpoint occured"? Do you have "break in main()" or similar option enabled in the IDE/debugger? The call to HAL_Init() is the first actual code in main() so that would happen in that case. Just continue executing, of course.

Comment: I don't have any idea how the break point occurred, I rechecked the code and debugged it and the same issue is happened. Is it because of the issue in the other code?!!

Comment: Do you have any reference to the enabling of ethernet port and getting the IP, I am having problem in understanding the function used in the DHCP to transfer the data packets in the stm32board.

Comment: [Look at this screenshot](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn80#New_set_of_preferences) from Eclipse, there's a setting that automatically breaks at the start, which would explain that nicely.

Comment: Thank you, I think the issue happened due to not assigning the memory.